# Student Question regarding molecular van der Waals volume and Polarizability

Tags: solubility, van-der-waals-behavior

I would like to request a crosscheck of my understandings regarding molecular van der Waals volume and polarizability. Please have a look through my statements about these 2 concepts below and point out any mistakes or inadequacies in my understanding.
Kindly please also provide citable authoritative research or review articles to any mistakes or inadequacies in my understanding. I do not have good access to books so articles it has to be.

Statement1
Van der Waals (vdW) bonds are the same thing (synonym) as vdW interaction.
vdW bond/interactions are molecular attractions resulting from dipole-dipole attraction, which means permanent polarity. And London dispersion forces, which are temporary polarity from either random fluctuation of the electron cloud around the atom nucleus or from an external electric field, e.g. a nearby polar molecule).
As such, vdW interaction occurs when the electron clouds of two molecules just touch each other.

Statement2
Van der Waals (vdW) volume of a molecule is (roughly) the volume of the electron cloud of that molecule. And is approximately the sum of the collective vdW volume of the constituent atoms of that molecule.

Statement3
vdW volume of an atom is calculated from the vdW radius of that atom, as a result, I can say that vdW volume of a molecule is calculated from the collective vdW radius of its constituent atoms.

Statement4
Polarizability is the ease by which the shape of the electron cloud is disrupted by either random fluctuations or external electrical influence. The higher the polarizability value the, easier for a molecule’s electron cloud shape to be disrupted.

Statement5
When a symmetric (non-polar) electron cloud is disrupted (being polarizable), the molecule becomes polarized and gains temporary polarity, meaning exists one positive and one negative end on the molecule (like a magnet).

Statment6
Polarizability value becomes higher when the molecular weight increases, meaning polarizability is positively correlated with molecular weight.

Statment7
And both Polarizability and molecular weight is positively correlated with vdW volume, meaning these 3 molecular parameters are positively correlated with one another, an increase of the value of any one increases the other 2. That is because, the greater the molecular mass, the greater the number of electrons. As a result, the electron cloud’s volume (vdW volume) becomes larger and easier to disrupt (high polarizability) since the nucleus has to influence a large number of electrons and electrons that are on higher orbitals with greater distance to the nucleus.

Statment8
High vdW volume molecules more readily form vdW bonds with other molecules because the larger electron cloud volume allows vdW interactions at a greater distance. And because to the larger electron cloud volume means greater polarizability and thus making it easier for London dispersion forces to arise, imbuing the molecule with temporary polarity.

Statment9
High vdW volume and high polarizability CAN indicate higher solubility in water. Although this is not always true and depends on the specific solution and solvent situation.

In a pro water solubility scenario,
The higher polarizability (and by correlation higher vdW volume) and resulting higher London dispersion forces imbuing non-polar molecules with temporary polarity allow non-polar molecules to dissolve in water, though not nearly as well as polar molecules.

Higher dispersion forces can also contribute further to the solubility of polar molecules.

Higher polarizability allows nearby polar molecules to induce polarity(dipoles) in non-polar molecules, thus making otherwise poorly soluble molecules become soluble in water. E.g. the Iron cation in hemoglobin polarizes non-polar oxygen, allowing it to dissolve in blood.

In an anti-water solubility scenario,
The high polarizability results in strong vdW bonding of non-polar molecules with each other, forming aggregates. In order for such molecules to dissolve in water, the vdW bonds need to be broken before allowing the formation of new vdW bonds with water molecules. This process
requires energy and thus making such molecules harder to dissolve in water.

These are the statements I request a cross-check. Aside from this, I would also like to request scientific authoritative link to tables of vdW volumes and polarizability values for the 20 canonical amino acids.
The table should have a legend explaining what a high numerical value for vdW volume and polarizability mean.

E.g. I know that vdW volume is expressed in cubic Angstrom (Å^3), therefore, a high numerical value e.g. 1000 Å^3 necessarily means a greater volume.

However, regarding polarizability, I found they can be expressed in many different ways and I don’t have the level of knowledge to say a high number means higher polarizability (ease to disrupt the electron cloud shape). Thus I need the reference to clearly state that high value means high polarizability.

Thanks for your attention and awaiting your kindness.